# Accessing Collections through blade foreach

Tags: laravel

[image]

```
@foreach ($despatchItems as $despatchItem)
            {{dd($despatchItem)}}
             <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputQty"  name="qty" value="{{$despatchItem->qty}}"></td>
@endforeach
```

I need to get the **qty** of these arrays(3 Collections are there in this case)

---

The Below worked for me

```
@foreach ($despatchItems as $collections)
    @foreach($collections as $collection)
        @foreach($collection as $despatchItem)
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputQty" name="qty" value="{{$despatchItem->qty}}"></td>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

My controller method looks like this

```
public function create($jobId)
{


  $job = Job::find($jobId);

  $despatches = $job->despatches;


  foreach ($despatches as $despatch) {
    $despatchItems['despatchItems'][] = $despatch->despatch_items;
  }

  return view('employees.invoices.create',compact('despatchItems','job'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have collection of DespatchItem

```
@foreach ($despatchItems as $despatchItem)
   {{dd($despatchItem->qty)}}
 @endforeach
```

If you need array of qty, try this:

```
$despatchItems->map(function ($despatchItem) {
    return $despatchItems->qty;
})
```

Comment: sorry small miscommunication from my side. I couldn't get your code to work. But i found another solution and i have posted it on top. I need to try your method again. If possible could you guide me a bit more.